# one of the men to

Tags: infinitives

Can one say

a. In our company, Tom is **the man to operate the lift fork**.

b. Tom is **our man to operate the lift fork.**

c. In our company, Tom is **one of the men to operate the lift fork**.

d. Tom is **one of our man to operate the lift fork**.

?

The intended meaning of (a) and (b) is that in our company Tom is the only man who has the task of operating the lift work.

The intended meaning of (c) and (d) is that in our company Tom is one of the men who operate the lift work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

None of your sentences are grammatically incorrect, but we can say what you are trying to say in the first one more succinctly and directly:

> 1. In our company, Tom operates the lift fork.

Or, if you like the *our*:

> 2. Tom is our lift fork operator.

As for the second thing you are trying to say, I think the sentence flows a bit more naturally with *who* instead of *to*:

> 3. In our company, Tom is one of the men **who operates** the lift fork.

Or:

> 4. Tom is one of the lift fork operators in our company.

Comment: Hm, no real results for `lift fork` in COCA or `a|the lift fork` on Google Ngrams. The usual name is *forklift (truck)*, but there are others on Wikipedia. I did find, let's say a certain five pages of bona fide Google results that include "lift fork", so either you heard it called that (unlikely), or you're copying what the asker said because that's not the main issue, and/or you don't know if that's what they want to call the machine. By the way, maybe they were going for a more informal variant with *man* there, but landed a bit off the mark: *Tom, our forklift **guy**...*

Comment: d. should be "Tom is one of our *men* to operate the lift fork." I also never heard of a lift fork before.

Comment: @userr2684291 - That’s a good point, but I thought the question was asking about the predicate more than the object. Wikipedia mentions that a forklift can also be called a _lift truck_ – I wonder if that’s what the OP was thinking of.